# Accessing variable which has comma during String concatenation

Tags: javascript, string, jsp

I am using following code in my jsp.

`<%= scriptletVar%>` returns a string like 12,000.When value is hard coded like 12,000 it displays it fine. But when this value comes as a scriptlet variable. It would only print 12. A separate `<tr>` tag would be created having value of 000.

I am finding it difficult to find how it works when hardcoded but not when fetched dynamically. There is something wrong with value having comma in it, but I am unable to figure a solution.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        $("#table tr:eq(1)").after("<tr><td class='row-highlight txt-ctr'>   <strong><span></span></strong></td>"+
                "<td class='row-highlight txt-right'><strong></strong></td><td class='row-highlight txt-right'><strong>" +<%= scriptletVar%> +"</strong></td>" +

//Rest of code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JavaScript is executed on client side and the JSP is executed on server side, the JSP is executed before the JavaScript and what is passed as `<%= scriptletVar%>` is just `12,000`. Not as string as you might expect, but as `Number, Number` as you are concatenating strings the single numbers are parsed to strings, but the `,` will be interpreted as separate two arguments of the function `after`. So you have to ensure that JavaScript knows that you want `12,000` to be handled as string. You do this by surrounding the value with double quotes `"` or just by not concatenating the string together, but writing `<%= scriptletVar%>` directly into the static string value.

So try the following:

```
$("#table tr:eq(1)").after("<tr><td class='row-highlight txt-ctr'>   <strong><span></span></strong></td>"+
    "<td class='row-highlight txt-right'><strong></strong></td><td class='row-highlight txt-right'><strong><%= scriptletVar%></strong></td>" +
```

Answer (score 0):

how about putting `<%= scriptletVar %>` into a variable and than put it into the jQuery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var someNumber = "<%= scriptletVar%>";
        $("#table tr:eq(1)").after("<tr><td class='row-highlight txt-ctr'>   <strong><span></span></strong></td>"+
                "<td class='row-highlight txt-right'><strong></strong></td><td class='row-highlight txt-right'><strong>" + someNumber  +"</strong></td>" +

//Rest of code
```

Comment: Tried that.Then a variable will be like var someNumber=12,000.So it will be erroneous.

Comment: Comma were the main source of problem. :)